# Date matching for spoken dates when using Twilio IVR?

Tags: date, datetime, twilio, ivr

This could pertain to other speech-to-text solutions, but we happen to be using Twilio.

Is there some easy means to do matching for a numerical date from spoken user input? For example, 08/11/2020 could be spoken as 'August Eleventh Twenty Twenty' 'Zero Eight one one Twenty Twenty' or various combinations. Because of how our app works, we need an exact match.

It seems that this would be a common issue, and I am wondering if there is already a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In general speech to text, Twilio doesn't have anything for parsing a date from speech. Within [Twilio Autopilot](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot) you can use the [built in type Twilio.DATE](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/built-in-field-types/twiliodate) to parse a date from a spoken string. This allows for detecting absolute examples like in your question, but also relative examples (like "tomorrow").